# How can I use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput with low resolution preview profile and take photos (while previewing) with high resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession

I want to use the `AVFoundation Famework` for previewing and capturing photos.
I created a `AVCaptureSession` and added `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to this session. I set the preset to `AVCaptureSessionPresetLow`.

Now I want to take a Photo in **full Resolution**. But within `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` the resolution is the same as in my preview delegate.

**Here is my Code:**

```
AVCaptureSession* cameraSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
cameraSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[cameraSession addOutput:output];

AVCaptureStillImageOutput* cameraStillImage = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[cameraSession addOutput:cameraStillImage];

// delegation
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);

[cameraSession startRunning];
```

**Take Photo:**

```
//[cameraSession beginConfiguration];
//[cameraSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];  <-- slow
//[cameraSession commitConfiguration];
[cameraStillImage captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:photoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
{
    ...
}];
```

I tried it by changing the preset to photo just befor capturing the image. But this is very slow (it takes 2-3 seconds to change the preset). I do not want to have such a big delay.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: When I tried (back when iOS 4 was still young), it was not possible to capture preview frames while in camera mode (at least without private APIs). It might be possible to access them via `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, but probably not via a public API.